# wxpython htmlWindow shows <h4> and <h6> tags italicised

Tags: html, wxpython, wxhtmlwindow

When using wx.htmlWindow in a standard application in python, using `self.htmlwin.SetPage("<h4>This text is italicised</h4><h6>This text is also italicised</h6>")` these two tags return an italicised result, however, this being the only code, it must be an internal issue, these two headers, the `<em>` tag and the `<i>` tag are the only italic tags, I tried using a regular browser to render HTML, but it renders it correctly, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Man, I'm pretty sure I once saw a W3C page somewhere that mentioned those elements may be styled by user agents any way they want; in particular that `h4` and up may be italic, rather than bold and a smaller font size than normal text. Still searching though.

Comment: [Here](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Headings.html) and [here](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_5.html) are pages that say a "typical rendering" for `h3` and `h5` is italic rather than bold.

Comment: well, testing this on chrome, edge, IE and firefox, they all showed up in bold rather than Italic, and because wxPython.htmlWindow doesn't support basic CSS, there's nothing I can do about it. :/